# Rails active storage, high availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, rails-activestorage

any idea about how to optimize active storage + amazon s3 + Heroku in order to have high availability on the images that the app serves? I use:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for
```

in order to generate an URL for a third party, this third makes a hundred or thousand requests to that URL.

the last test that I ran was about 400 request and I got 230 with status OK (200), but for the rest 170 I got a fail status (500)

any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: Can you cache the url contents?

Comment: yes sure could be an option, but I don't know how to do it, One idea that I have is too put an nginx in front, but I am not sure how to configure that

Comment: Start with basic Rails caching...https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html